# Save to database every 5 iterations but what happens if there are less?

Tags: c#

I have let's say 100 items fetched form database that I need to update and save back to db. I want to save them in batches so basically let's say every 5'th change  save. But what if I have 4 records only? The save logic is never hit.

```
.....
int i =0;
foreach (var item in records)
{
   item.Property += 10;

   if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) // if records contains 4 items this will never be saved
   {
       ctx.SaveChanges();
   }

   i++;
 }
```

Comment: Just add `ctx.SaveChanges()` right after the `foreach` loop maybe? Even with an `if(i%5 != 0)` so you save only if needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simply

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in records)
{
    item.Property += 10;

    if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) // if records contains 4 items this will never be saved
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    i++;
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition before it because it would hit also after the loop once again.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in records)
{
    item.Property += 10;

    if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) // if records contains 4 items this will never be saved
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    i++;
}

if (records.Count() < 5) // if records contains less than 5 items -> save
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    int i = 0;
    bool saved = true; 
    foreach (var item in records)
    {
         item.Property += 10;

         if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0)
         {
             ctx.SaveChanges();
             saved = true; 
         }
         else 
         {
             saved = false; 
         }
         i++;
    }

    if (!saved) // if there are any unsaved items then save it here
    {
         ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```